# mv: rename X to Y: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, zsh

On mac os (with zsh), I often find myself having to copy the last downloaded file to the current directory.

Having already defined the function lastn as follows:

```
function lastn() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo ""
        echo "Usage:"
        echo "lastn <path> [n]"
        echo ""
  fi
  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
      ls -lht $argv[1] | head -10
    else
      ls -lht $argv[1] | head -$argv[2]
  fi
}
```

I have tried these scripts:

`{echo "~/Downloads"; lastn ~/Downloads 2 | tail -1 | sed 's/.* //';} | tr "\n" "/" | sed 's/\/$//' | xargs -I % mv % ./`

`ORIGIN=$({echo "~/Downloads"; lastn ~/Downloads 2 | tail -1 | sed 's/.* //';} | tr "\n" "/" | sed 's/\/$//'); mv $ORIGIN ./`

In both cases, I always get an error of the type:

`mv: rename ~/Downloads/filename to ./filename: No such file or directory`

On the other hand, if I simply copy the output of the first part of both scripts:

`{echo "~/Downloads"; lastn ~/Downloads 2 | tail -1 | sed 's/.* //';} | tr "\n" "/" | sed 's/\/$//'`

and use it as-is by pasting it as the first argoment of mv, the command works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [How can I expand a tilde `~` as part of a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399407/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, that was extremely useful. So if I got it right I need to always use an absolute path, without representing my home directory as tilde, right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use absolute paths. You just need to rewrite your function like this:

```sh
lastn() {
  # Reset all options to safe defaults for this function only.
  emulate -LR zsh -o noshortloops -o warncreateglobal -o extendedglob

  # Get files sorted by modification date (or failing that, an empty array).
  local -a files=( $1/*(Nom) )

  case $# in
    0)
      echo "Usage:"
      echo "lastn <path> [n]"
      return 1
      ;;
    1)
      reply=( $files[1] )
      ;;
    *)
      reply=( $files[1,$2] )
      ;;
  esac

  # This is not necessary, but gives the user something to look at.
  echo $reply

  # Report success only when we actually have something to return.
  (( $#reply > 0 ))
}
```

Then you can simply do the following:

```sh
lastn ~/Downloads 2 && mv $reply .
```

The last line of the function makes it so that, if we don't get any results, then the command following `&&` won't get executed.

Comment: This exact solution would create other issues by changing the output of lastn, but could be adapted to suit my use case. On the other hand, I tested on my laptop and got this error:
`./testMove.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`
`./testMove.sh: line 3: \`  local -a files=( $1/*(Nom) )'`

Comment: I tried the function above on a fresh Zsh with no config and it works fine. You might have set one of the options that changes Zsh's syntax.

Comment: @roccobarbi I updated the function. Please try again.

Comment: I still get the exat same error.

Comment: By the way, my adaptation (unrelated to the error, which I get on your code above as well as on my version, on separate files) would simply be:
`testMove() {
        local -a files=(~/Downloads/*(Nom))
        if test -z "$files"
                then mv files[1] .
                else echo "~/Downloads directory is empty"
        fi
}`

Which would leave the original function untouched.

Comment: "I still get the exat same error." That's really strange. As I said, if I declare this function in a clean install of Zsh, it runs just fine. You must have some non-default config that's messing things up.